# Overlapping while printing values in label

Tags: iphone, uilabel, sum

i want to print sum of last value but following code shows all values in a label by overlap printing so how can i show only last sum of values in a labels

```
-(void)dataPrinting
{
int total=0;
for (int i = 0; i < [totalData count]; i++)
{
    total +=i;
}
UILabel * lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,75, 200, 60)];
lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",total];
lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:60];
lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[scrollView addSubview:lbl];
 }
```

Comment: but i want show only one value that should be last value

Comment: last value means last value in the array or sum of all the values in the array?

Comment: sum of all the values in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void)dataPrinting
   {
 int total=0;
  for (int i = 0; i < [totalData count]; i++)
     {
     total += [totalData  objectAtindex:i];  /// you need to access value in the array
   }
UILabel * lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,75, 200, 60)];
lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",total];
lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:60];
lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[scrollView addSubview:lbl];
}
```

Comment: the above code gives some error like receiver type NSMutableArray for instance message does not declare method with selector objectAtIndex

Comment: Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'id', which is not a constant size in non-fragile ABI

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "sum of last value". However you can access the last element of your array using *lastObject*.

```
int total = [[totalData lastObject] intValue];
```

**Update:**

What you're doing in your code is adding the index `i` to `total`. Use the following instead:
    total += [[totalData objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

If you see labels overlapping each other you're probably calling the `dataPrinting` method multiple times. And since you don't remove the old ones they will stay. You create a property of your label or give your label a tag and reuse the same label and simple change the text on your label.

In your header:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *totalLabel;
```

In your implementation:

```
-(UILabel)totalLabel
{
    if (_totalLabel == nil)
    {
        _totalLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,75, 200, 60)];
        _totalLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:60];
        _totalLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        _totalLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [scrollView addSubview:_totalLabel];
    }
    return _totalLabel;
}

-(void) dataPrinting
{
    int total=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [totalData count]; i++)
    {
        total += [[totalData objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    }
    self.totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",total];;
}
```

Comment: sir totalData contains many numbers i calculate sum of the all numbers